# Не подключаются кастомные шрифты на GitHub Pages

Tags: html, css, шрифты, github-pages

Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/bergdev/bergdev.github.io

Ссылка на сайт: https://bergdev.github.io/BergDesign/index.html

Я попытался подключить шрифт Cony с помощью

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Cony;
  src: url(.../BergDesign/fonts/19939.otf);
}
```

А также

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Cony;
  src: url(/fonts/19939.otf);
}
```

И использовать его на .textxs и .textlg из style.css.
При том что на моём компьютере это работало.

Ничего не вышло. В чём причина и как пофиксить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. На дворе 2020. Сейчас [принято](https://webformyself.com/ponyatie-formatov-shriftov-i-kak-vyzhat-iz-nix-maksimum-dlya-veb/) использовать шрифты формата `woff` или `woff2`. Особенно с `@font-face`. Конвертируйте свой `otf`-ник Сервис [тут](https://convertio.co/ru/otf-woff/)
2. Укажите правильный путь. Обычно он такой: `"../fonts/19939.woff"`
   Вы забыли кавычки и то, что на сервере у Вашего сайта другой путь, чем на локальном компьютере и Ваш шрифт просто не находит.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не верный путь до файлов шрифтов. Попробуйте так `url(./../fonts/19939.otf);` или так `url(../fonts/19939.otf);`